# Distribute identical balls in identical boxes with nonempty boxes having different amounts of balls

Tags: combinatorics

As the title suggests, I need to find the number of ways to distribute $n$ identical balls in $n$ identical boxes with nonempty boxes having different amounts of balls.

I am not sure which way to approach the problem.

The current thought is that it would be equivalent with finding the solution of how many combinations of the numbers $1,\cdots,10$ equal $n$ but I am not sure this is easier than the original problem.

Comment: This is about partitions into different parts; see here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Exactly what I needed. In the article you linked the exact case is called "partition with distinct parts"